# noetic createTimer always segfault

Tags: ros, libroscpp, roscpp, timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

After introducing ROS to my program with success, i wanted to use it more and added timer.
I am using the same code on both Ubuntu20/noetic and Ubuntu18/melodic without any issue.
But with timer i have a problem. On melodic it works fine, on noetic it always segfault when i call createTimer.

I tried the sample in the wiki for timers and that simple code also segfaults. I tried with different ways of calling createTimer with different callback binding style but all segfaults.

```
void callback1(const ros::TimerEvent&) {
    ROS_INFO("Callback 1 triggered");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Timer timer1 = n.createTimer(ros::Duration(0.1), callback1);
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

Some basics information

```
ROS_VERSION=1 ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/noetic/share
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/noetic/etc/ros
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros
ROS_DISTRO=noetic
```

noetic is installed with apt, all default packages on a new fresh install of Ubuntu20 server
All parameters to start roscore or my test program are defaults.

Stack trace is not useful but i have no idea how i could have more details at one line it is actually crashing inside libroscpp

```
#0  0x00007ffff7f0a36e in ros::NodeHandle::createTimer(ros::Duration, boost::function<void (ros::TimerEvent const&)> const&, bool, bool) const () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroscpp.so.2d
#1  0x0000555555558b97 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe1e8) at /home/worker/main.cpp:11
```

To install i do

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt install ros-noetic-ros-base libroscpp-dev
```

To compile my code, i use cmake and link to roscpp using

```
pkg_check_modules(libros REQUIRED roscpp)
target_include_directories(mybin PUBLIC ${libros_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(mybin ${libros_LIBRARIES})
```

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410806/noetic-createtimer-always-segfault/) by [qualiticsbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/128909/qualiticsbe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Stack trace is not useful but i have no idea how i could have more details at one line it is actually crashing inside libroscpp
>
> ```
> #0  0x00007ffff7f0a36e in ros::NodeHandle::createTimer(ros::Duration, boost::function<void (ros::TimerEvent const&)> const&, bool, bool) const () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroscpp.so.2d
> #1  0x0000555555558b97 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe1e8) at /home/worker/main.cpp:11
> ```

actually, it's *very* useful, and this most likely already shows the cause: `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroscpp.so.2d`.

There are no artefacts from ROS Noetic proper which install into anything else but `/opt/ros/noetic`.

In other words: the library `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroscpp.so.2d` is **not** part of ROS Noetic.

> To install i do
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
> curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -
> sudo apt install ros-noetic-ros-base libroscpp-dev
> ```

Similar to the above: `libroscpp-dev` is not part of ROS Noetic (in fact, `libroscpp-dev` is not really part of any ROS version).

All packages part of ROS Noetic will have the `ros-noetic-` prefix (like `ros-noetic-ros-base`).

What's most likely happening is you're mixing ROS Noetic proper with the [UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages). That won't work reliably, as you've already found out. See also [“upstream packages” increasingly becoming a problem](https://discourse.ros.org/t/upstream-packages-increasingly-becoming-a-problem/10902/) on ROS Discourse.

I'd recommend to purge all upstream variants of ROS packages and make sure you have a sane ROS Noetic install.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [qualiticsbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/128909/qualiticsbe/) on 2022-12-27**:
Oh wow! Ok that was a huge help and i figured it out.
Linking to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroscpp.so.2d` was indeed the root cause of my problem.

So first, i removed the package libroscpp-dev and only keep `ros-noetic-ros-base`

For cmake i do instead

```
find_package(libros REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp)
```

That way it links to `libroscpp.so` inside `/opt/ros/noetic`.
I don't know why i have python prompt for a cpp binary that way but it's working so i don't mind.

```
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Found PY_em: /home/god_kane/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/em.py  
-- Using empy: /home/god_kane/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/em.py
```

Guess i fell into that upstream package trap like many other new ros user.

Thanks!

**Comment by [qualiticsbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/128909/qualiticsbe/) on 2022-12-27**:
I now know why i used pkg_check_modules(libros REQUIRED roscpp) before, it was not to be annoyed with python. In a cross-compiling environment i can't compile because catkin bothers me about it while i really don't care about python.
Can i ignore python completely while still linking the proper librairies?